# Receiving error with griddb-python package

Tags: pip, griddb

I am trying to install griddb-python using pip

```
!pip install griddb-python
```

and recieving error of

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [8 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
  running build
  running build_ext
  building '_griddb_python' extension
  swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
  swig.exe -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
  error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
  [end of output]
```

is this system or python pip error?

Comment: https://github.com/griddb/python_client/#quickstart-windows Also you need to install `swig.exe`.

Comment: Thanks, okay will install swig.exe. Update you if needed